# Как настроить часовой пояс в Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В оригинальной документации django в примере создаётся веб-приложение для опросов. И в самом начале говорится что можно настроить часовой пояс. По умолчанию он стоит на `"UTC"`, а мне надо `UTC +05`, но если я указываю его так, то мне пишет что неверный формат временной зоны.

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Comment: `если я указываю его так` добавьте пример как вы меняли часовой пояс

Comment: @gil9red, как раз и есть пример прямо перед этой фразой. Я вместо `"UTC"` пишу `"UTC +05"`

Comment: `TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul'`
`USE_TZ = True` только это для +2  остальные тут https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Я просил показать как это было изменено в коде/команде

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, спасибо большое! Всё заработало)

Comment: @gil9red, вот прям вся строка: `TIME_ZONE = "UTC +05"`

Comment: @DGDays, понятно, посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311392/5909792

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, оформите, пожалуйста как ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для настройки часовых поясов надо использовать параметры `TIME_ZONE` в настройках проекта(`settings.py`).

Пример

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Istanbul' #UTC +2 
USE_TZ = True
```

По умолчанию, поддержка часовых поясов отключена. Для включения используется второй параметр в примере(`USE_TZ`).
Посмотреть все остальные `TIME_ZONE` можно например на википедии https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones