# Не могу выставить правильную временную зону в Django

Tags: python, django, utc

Я в самом начале изучения Django. Извиняюсь за глупы вопрос) Создал проект в самом начале не указал временную зону, добавил записи в базу данных и провел миграции. Как правильно исправить временную зону? Чтоб ранее добавленные записи выводились в нужной временной зоне.
Пробовал изменить в settings настройку "UTC" на "UTC+6" выдает ошибку. Спасибо. TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

Comment: [Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207286/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81-%D0%B2-django)